# Controller AdminAddresses missed or not valid PrestaShop 1.7.5.1

Tags: controller, prestashop

I'm using ps v 1.7.5.1 with purchased theme.

When in PrestaShop BO I click on Customers > Addresses I get this error: AdimnAddresses controller is missed or not valid.

Some help?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

check your Prestashop installation or files / folder permission,
looks like you're missing the:

```
/controllers/admin/AdminAddressesController.php
```

file.

Comment: Try recovering the complete /classes and /controllers folder from the Prestashop ZIP file of the same version.

Comment: Downloadi the ZIP installer again and recover the file from there ( https://www.prestashop.com/en/previous-versions )

Comment: - I donwoladed prestashop_1.7.5.1
- uploaded the missed file AdminAddressesController.php form prestashop_1.7.5.1\prestashop\controllers\admin (zip file folder) to /www/controllers/admin (my site folder)
- opened the Addresses link in PrestaShop
- The server returned a "500 Internal Server Error"...

Comment: Try enabling debug mode from advanced parameters and refresh the page so you can see the complete error behind the 500 error.

Comment: ahah Awesome! when i turn ON the debug mode... the addresses page displays everything correct (name, addresses, etc...), but when I turn it OFF again... 500 Internal Server Error :(

Comment: I just had to clear cache and everything work fine! Thank you very much for your support it was great! :)